# Why is this alert box not popping up when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, input, replace, alert

I've been writing a script to check for reflective XSS vulnerabilities. So far, it has an input for a URL with * in place of queries and an error checker for malformed URLs. It also has a file uploader for users to upload "payloads". However, I recently made a part that replaces * with the contents of the payload, and then for debugging purposes, I made it `alert()` the variable with the file contents. However, its not working. Here's my code:

```js
function selectPayload(y) {

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
  fr.onload = function() {

    var dir = fr.result;
    var payload = y.replace("*", fr.result);
    alert(payload);

  };

}

function myFunction() {

  var errors = [];
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

  if (!x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://")) {

    errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS in URL');

  }

  if (!x.includes("*")) {

    errors.push('missing * in place of query')

  }

  // Renders errors
  if (errors.length) {

    x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!';

  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  selectPayload(x);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

</head>

<body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

  <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
  <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
  <h4>Please report all issues to
    <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at email@example.com.</h4>
  <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
  <br />

  <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
  <h5>Example: <code>https://www.google.com/#q=*</code></h5>
  <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

  <h4>Select a payload:</h4>
  <h5>Default payloads in <code>payloads</code></h5>
  <input type="file" id="file"> <button onclick="selectPayload()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are getting an error because `y` is undefined and you are trying to use a `replace` on it. On the `onclick` of the file input submit button you call `selectPayload` instead of `myFunction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: I've found code that will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

</head>

<body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

  <script> 

    function selectPayload() {

      var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      var fr = new FileReader();
      fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
      fr.onload = function() {

        var dir = fr.result;
        var payload = x.replace("*", fr.result);
        alert(payload);

      };

    }

    function myFunction() {

      var errors = [];
      var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

      if (!x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://")) {

        errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS in URL');

      }

      if (!x.includes("*")) {

        errors.push('missing * in place of query')

      }

      // Renders errors
      if (errors.length) {

        x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!';

      }

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

      }


  </script>

  <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
  <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
  <h4>Please report all issues to
    <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
  <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
  <br />

  <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
  <h5>Example: <code>https://www.google.com/#q=*</code></h5>
  <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

  <h4>Select a payload:</h4>
  <h5>Default payloads in <code>payloads</code></h5>
  <input type="file" id="file"> <button onclick="selectPayload()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the second button calling the wrong function. Changed to call `myFunction()` instead of `selectPayload()`. Unless you intended to call `selectPayload()` with the second button, in which case you neet to pass it an argument like it expects.

```js
function selectPayload(y) {

  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsText(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
  fr.onload = function() {

    var dir = fr.result;
    var payload = y.replace("*", fr.result);
    alert(payload);

  };

}

function myFunction() {

  var errors = [];
  var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;

  if (!x.includes("http://") && !x.includes("https://")) {

    errors.push('missing HTTP or HTTPS in URL');

  }

  if (!x.includes("*")) {

    errors.push('missing * in place of query')

  }

  // Renders errors
  if (errors.length) {

    x = 'Error: ' + errors.join(', ') + '!';

  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  selectPayload(x);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>Slingshot.XSS</title>

</head>

<body style="font-family:monospace;" align="center">

  <h2>Slingshot.XSS</h2>
  <h3>Slingshot.XSS is a script that launches pre-loaded XSS payloads at a target to test its vulnerabilities.</h3>
  <h4>Please report all issues to
    <a href="https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss/issues"></a> or contact me at keeganjkuhn@gmail.com.</h4>
  <a href="github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
  <br />

  <h4>Enter a URL with <b>*</b> in the place of query.</h4>
  <h5>Example: <code>https://www.google.com/#q=*</code></h5>
  <input type="text" id="myText" placeholder="Enter a URL"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <p id="demo">No Submitted URL</p>

  <h4>Select a payload:</h4>
  <h5>Default payloads in <code>payloads</code></h5>
  <input type="file" id="file"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```